# Rendering a Wordpress website as html files locally

Tags: node.js, wordpress

I can use any technology in my local environment, but I cannot use anything like node.js or php for the production server.

So far I have built the website with nunjucks, a templating engine that outputs html files that I then simply upload them to the production server, node.js only needs to run on my local environment.

Is there any way to use Wordpress like that? I want wordpress for the wysiwyg editor and for the SEO plugins.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why your can't use node.js or php on your production server.

Comment: I don't really know, the sysadmin won't allow it, it's the same server that hosts other crucial applications and php and node.js are considered insecure.

Comment: A quick search gave me this: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/ - maybe that could be useful?

Comment: If you can't use PHP on your production server - wordpress will be uselless

Comment: Than you, I have also found static wordpress plugins, they seem to be the way, I tested this one and it works well, can even publish the static site on it's own: https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

If I get that right, than you would like to setup a wordpress site locally and then turn that into static html files, which you can upload to the production server?

In that case `wget` or `curl` are your friends. To download an entire site as static html something like that will do (adjust parameters and urls as you need)

```
wget \
 --recursive \
 --no-clobber \
 --page-requisites \
 --html-extension \
 --convert-links \
 --restrict-file-names=windows \
 --domains website.org \
 --no-parent \
     localhost:12345
```

Comment: thank you, I found a plugin that does this well, of course the search and comments do not work, but it works: https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

There are various plugins to achieve this, I tested this one and it works: https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/

Of course there is no search or commenting in the static version, but that is to be expected.